# AJAX Struts 1.x using tiles without jQuery

Tags: javascript, ajax, struts, struts-1, apache-tiles

I faced with problem using tiles in struts 1/x.

For example I have next files

as `tiles-def.xml`

```
<definition name="list.page" extends="main.layout">
    <put name="title" value="List Page" />
    <put name="body" value="/pages/tiles/body/list.jsp" />
</definition>


<definition name="view.page" extends="main.layout">
    <put name="title" value="View Page" />
    <put name="body" value="/pages/tiles/body/ViewItem.jsp" />
</definition>

<definition name="add.page" extends="main.layout">
    <put name="title" value="Add and Edit Page" />
    <put name="body" value="/pages/tiles/body/AddItem.jsp"></put>
</definition>
```

My   `struts-config.xml`

```
<action-mappings>
        <action path="/items" name="itemsForm"
            type="org.springframework.web.struts.DelegatingActionProxy"
            parameter="method" validate="false">
            <forward name="list" path="list.page" />
            <forward name="view" path="view.page" />
            <forward name="add" path="add.page" />          
            <forward name="delete" path="/index.jsp" />
            <forward name="edit" path="add.page" />         
        </action>
///
</action-mapping>
```

And for example link on my list.jsp as

```
<a href="#" onclick="SendRequest('GET', 'news.do', 'method=view&amp;newsMessage.id=${news.id}', null)"><bean:message key="link.view" /></a>
```

And JS for ajax

```
function CreateRequest() {
  var Request = false;
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // Gecko-compatible browsers
    Request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
    // IE
    try {
      Request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); //Newer IE
    } catch (CatchException) {          
      Request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); //Older IE
    }
  }

  if (!Request) {
    alert("Impossible create XMLHTTPREquest");
  }
  return Request;
}
```

-

```
/**
 * Function sending request to file on server
 * 
 * r_method - type request GET or POST r_path - path to file r_args - args as
 * a1&a2 r_handler - function handler response from server
 * 
 */
function SendRequest(r_method, r_path, r_args, r_handler) {

    // Create Request
    var Request = CreateRequest();

    // Check existing request
    if (!Request) {
        return;
    }

    // Set user handler
    Request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        // If exchange data was finished
        if (Request.readyState == 4) {

            if (Request.status == 200) {
                // Give management user handler

                //r_handler(Request);
                document.getElementById("content_container").innerHTML = Request.responseText;

            }
        }
    };

    // Check if need to create GET-request
    if (r_method.toLowerCase() == "get" && r_args.length > 0) {
        r_path += "?" + r_args;
    }

    // Initialize connection
    Request.open(r_method, r_path, true);

    if (r_method.toLowerCase() == "post") {
        // If this is POST
        // Set header
        Request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type",
                "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        //Send request
        Request.send(r_args);
    }
    else {
        //If it's GET
        //Send null-request
        Request.send(null);
    }
}
```

And action on server

```
public ActionForward view(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws Exception {

        response.setContentType(RESP_CONTENT_TYPE);

        //some operationss
        if (itemsForView.getId() == null) {
            //return mapping.findForward(ERROR_ACTION);
            return new ActionForward("/pages/error.jsp");
        } else {
            itemsForm.setItems(itemsForView);
            //return mapping.findForward(VIEW_ACTION);          
            return new ActionForward("/pages/tiles/body/View.jsp");
        }
    }
```

I confused because I find next example [Using AJAX With Struts and Tiles](http://www.createsoft.co.uk/blog/2008/05/using-ajax-with-struts-and-tiles/)

Please, give me explanation or links on good article.

Comment: The article you link to seems a good one to me. What's the specific issue you would like an answer to?